# Turn 4 horizontal columns into to 2 blocks of 2 when it goes smaller than 992px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Running Bootstrap and I've got 4 horizontal columns with a title, png icon and a small description.

I have got the text part to hide when it goes to Sm and Xs which makes it nice and clean.

However, I want turn the block of 4 into 2 blocks on one line and the other 2 below when it passes the 992px mark. Any ideas?

```
<section id="features" class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 main-content">
    <h2 class="servicesoff">Services Offered</h2>
    <div class="feat-single">
        <ul class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <li>
                <a href="link1.php"><img src="/icon1.png" alt="Service 1">
                <h3 class="servicestitle"><a href="Service1.php">Service 1</a></h3>         
                <p class="servicestext hidden-sm hidden-xs">loremipsum</p>      
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="link2.php"><img src="/icon1.png" alt="Service 2">
                <h3 class="servicestitle"><a href="Service2.php">Service 2</a></h3>     
                <p class="servicestext hidden-sm hidden-xs">loremipsum</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="link3.php"><img src="/icon3.png" alt="Service 3">
                <h3 class="servicestitle"><a href="Service3.php">Service 3</a></h3>     
                <p class="servicestext hidden-sm hidden-xs">loremipsum</p>  
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="link4.php"><img src="/icon4.png" alt="Service 4">
                <h3 class="servicestitle"><a href="Service4.php">Service 4</a></h3> 
                <p class="servicestext hidden-sm hidden-xs">loremipsum</p>  
            </li>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: seeing your HTML/CSS would make this a whole lot easier. However, i would suggest media queries for something like this

Comment: do you have an example code?

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML and CSS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have only 1 bootstrap column, judging by `col-sm-12`

In order to achieve your goal consider the following structure:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <!-- Block 1 -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <!-- Block 2 -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <!-- Block 3 -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <!-- Block 4 -->
     </div>
</div>
```

`col-lg-3` takes 25% width on large screens

`col-sm-6` takes 50% width on small screens

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you require, you'll need to apply the col- styling to the different columns you have.  Firstly, looking at the bootstrap documentation for the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), devices under 992px fall into the small and extra small categories.

If you have 4 columns on medium and large devices, each column will need the class `col-md-3` and `col-lg-3`.  To change this when the device window is smaller, you'll need the columns to take up 6 grid units each, so `col-sm-6` and `col-xs-6` should also be added to each column.

Comment: Note that `col-sm-6` implies `col-xs-6`, so only first is needed.

Comment: I tried adding to the li which is the individual column in this case but nothing happened "<li class="col-sm-6">"

Answer (score 0):

i thin you can achieve what you want by using the some classes of the bootstrap predefined grid system

```css
.feat-single ul li{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<section id="features" class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 main-content">
<h2 class="servicesoff">Services Offered</h2>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="feat-single">
            <ul class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
                <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <a href="link1.php"><img src="/icon1.png" alt="Service 1">
                    <h3 class="servicestitle"><a href="Service1.php">Service 1</a></h3>         
                    <p class="servicestext hidden-sm hidden-xs">loremipsum</p>      
                </li>
                <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
                    <a href="link2.php"><img src="/icon1.png" alt="Service 2">
                    <h3 class="servicestitle"><a href="Service2.php">Service 2</a></h3>     
                    <p class="servicestext hidden-sm hidden-xs">loremipsum</p>
                </li>
                <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
                    <a href="link3.php"><img src="/icon3.png" alt="Service 3">
                    <h3 class="servicestitle"><a href="Service3.php">Service 3</a></h3>     
                    <p class="servicestext hidden-sm hidden-xs">loremipsum</p>  
                </li>
                <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
                    <a href="link4.php"><img src="/icon4.png" alt="Service 4">
                    <h3 class="servicestitle"><a href="Service4.php">Service 4</a></h3> 
                    <p class="servicestext hidden-sm hidden-xs">loremipsum</p>  
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</section>
```

and here is the demo working code for these

**[Demo working code](https://jsfiddle.net/m6984whw/9/)**

and for more understanding here is the reference document of the bootstrap grid system

**[Reference Document](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)**

Comment: @MeldaS please check out the answer